# LINQ without using cycle

Tags: c#, .net, linq

During optimalization of the code I found method which use foreach cycle in LINQ. I would like to use it without this cycle. Any advise how can I change it?

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ListAllCoursesWithArea()
{
    List<Tuple<string,string>> final = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    Tuple<string, string> tmp;

    var books = (
     from temp in bookListLoader.LoadList()
     group temp by new { temp.CourseCode } into g
     select g.First()
     ).ToList();

    foreach (BookListRecord i in books)
    {
        tmp = new Tuple<string, string>(i.CourseCode, i.Area);
        final.Add(tmp);
    }
    return final;
}
```

I tried this but it gives me error message "Identifier Expected":

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ListAllCoursesWithArea()
{
    var books = (
    from temp in bookListLoader.LoadList()
    group temp by new { temp.CourseCode } into g
    select g.First().(new Tuple<g.CourseCode,g.Area>())
    ).ToList();
    return books;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readable and shortest way:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ListAllCoursesWithArea()
{
    return bookListLoader
                .LoadList()
                .GroupBy(x => x.CourseCode)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x.CourseCode, x.Area));
}
```

Or in your example:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ListAllCoursesWithArea()
{
    return from temp in bookListLoader.LoadList()
           group temp by new { temp.CourseCode } into g
           let x = g.First()
           select new Tuple<string, string>(x.CourseCode, x.Area);

}
```

Comment: Could probably flatten the 2 selects into a single select-many.

Comment: @code4life probably yes but in this case we need to evaluate `First()` twice, needn't we?

Comment: No, I think you can just create the Tuple out of the `First()`.